# Error with database authentication in Apache Guacamole

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, authentication, mariadb

I'm setup a new Ubuntu Server 22.04 VM and am following the documentation here:

https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/jdbc-auth.html

Guacamole 1.4 installs fine along with Tomcat9 and Nginx proxy; I can access the site fine with user-mapping.xml

After installing MariaDB, importing the schema files and placing extensions / lib files I am getting an error on the site:

> ERROR
> An error has occurred and this action cannot be completed. If the
> problem persists, please notify your system administrator or check
> your system logs.

However I am not seeing any errors in Tomcat's catalina log files to further troubleshoot.

Files:
/etc/guacamole/extensions/guacamole-auth-jdbc-mysql-1.4.0.jar
/etc/guacamole/lib/mariadb-java-client-3.0.5.jar
/etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties

```
# Hostname and port of guacamole proxy
guacd-hostname: localhost
guacd-port:     4822

# Allow 24 hours for sign-ins
api-session-timeout: 1440

# Database authentication
mysql-hostname: localhost
mysql-port: 3306
mysql-database: guacamole
mysql-username: guacamole_user
mysql-password: mZWY********9YoA
mysql-server-timezone: America/New_York
```

I'd appreciate any help with where I'm going wrong and/or locate the necessary log files to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to MariaDB Java Connector 7 seems to have fixed the error:

/etc/guacamole/lib/mariadb-java-client-1.8.0.jar

```
# java --version
openjdk 18-ea 2022-03-22
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18-ea+36-Ubuntu-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18-ea+36-Ubuntu-1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Never did find any error logs however.